# 64-bit sharemem.pas/borlndmm.dll XE2

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, delphi-xe2

A few questions:

1. Do Delphi XE2 64-bit apps link in borlndmm.dll when sharemem.pas 
   is used just like in 32-bit?
2. Are their export signatures the same as the 32-bit borlndmm.dll?
3. Is it also called borlndmm.dll?

Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Q:     Do Delphi XE2 64-bit apps link in borlndmm.dll when
>   sharemem.pas is used just like in 32-bit?

A: Yes, Delphi uses a 64 bit version of the borlndmm.dll library

> Q:     Are their export signatures the same as the 32-bit
>   borlndmm.dll?

A: Yes , the signatures are the same.

> Q :     Is it also called borlndmm.dll?

A: Yes is called **borlndmm.dll** and is located on the *bin64* folder of your rad studio (delphi) installation.